# Estimation of the quantile at a certain value for normal distribution using density and qnorm

Tags: r, quantile, kernel-density

I am computing quantiles but I can[t get a good estimation:

Suppose we have the next normal random variables

```
set.seed(1234)
data<-rnorm(10000,1800,150)
hist(data,probability = TRUE,xlim=c(500,3000))
plot(density(data),col="red")
q1<-qnorm(.997,mean = 1800,sd=150,lower.tail = TRUE)
q2<-quantile(density(data)$x,probs = 0.997)

q1
q2
```

abline(v=q1,col="blue",lwd=2)
   abline(v=q2,col="blue",lwd=2,lty=2)

Seeing that, the two quantiles are  not close, are different in almost 200 units.

I have tried increasing the parameter n in density but I can't get a better estimation. I have simulated more random variables and always is so different.

I am doing something wrong? How to asses this error?

Comment: Why do you use `density()` ? if you want to estimate the 0.997 quantile of your data, you should use quantile(data,0.997).

Comment: I used density because I want to estimate the real density and find the quantile of the density, for that reason I considered the values of density(data)$x, because for instance If i consider a small sample, and compute the density of the data, knowing that the sample comes from a normal distribution, the quantile does not coincide. I want to estimate the real quantile of the distribution of the data, supposing that I dont know the distribution of the data.

Comment: I also can't understand why you use `density` and it's `x` result. `x` are equally distributed points along dimension (axis) where density was estimated.

Comment: @user3483060: the problem is that, by doing so, you're not looking for the .997 quantile of your data but the .997 quantile of the _estimated_ density of your function. In particular, if you play with the bandwith of the kernel (`bw` argument of `density`), you'll see that it changes the output value a lot.

Comment: yes, the idea that I have is to estimate a density for my dataset and find the quantile of that density, I think that this should coincide with the theoretical normal density. In practice I dont know the real distribution, the idea is to use the estimations and find the estimated quantile.